# Python Anywhere Flask ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, flask

My file structure for a Flask app in Python Anywhere is as follows:

```
mysite
  ├── main.py (contains main = Blueprint('main', __name__), not sure if this is relevant)
  ├── __init__.py (contains app = Flask(__name__))
  ├── templates
     ├── html...
```

I am on step 5.1 of this guide https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-host-your-flask-app-on-pythonanywhere-for-free-df8486eb6a42 . According to the guide, I am supposed to import my Flask(**name**) object from my root file. The problem is that my app = Flask(**name**) is inside of my **init**.py instead of main.py, as it is in the guide. As a result, I am receiving this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from main import app as application
```

To debug this, I visited https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/ but still cannot understand how to fix my problem. In the foo/bar example, I feel that my situation most matches the 3rd example since my variable (app) is actually contained in the **init**.py and not main.py. However, my main.py is a Python file and not a directory like it is in that example and so I am confused if my situation matches any of the examples at all. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like two things, you need to import from the package which is `mysite`, and `app` won't be in the `main` module, it will be directly importable from `mysite` (because it's in `__init__.py`). So should be `from mysite import app as application`

Comment: I tried that and am now getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'. My working directory for Python Anywhere has been set to /home/mysite (in case this is relevant). @Tgsmith61591

Comment: Just figured it out actually ,turns out I have to write the WSGI file differently
Instead of from (...) import (...) as application we needed to do:
from project import create_app
application = create_app()
Found my answer here after digging in the forums: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/8397/